# Import sorting error. Flake8 isort error "I001 isort found an import in the wrong position"

Tags: flake8, isort

How can I fix it?
Test error: flake8 isort found an import in the wrong position

[image: 1]

````
from api.v1.filters import TitleFilter
from api.v1.permissions import (AuthorAdminModeratorOrReadOnly, IsAdmin,
                                IsAdminOrReadOnly)
from api.v1.serializers import (CategorySerializer, CommentSerializer,
                                ConfirmationCodeSerializer, GenreSerializer,
                                ReviewSerializer, SignUpSerializer,
                                TitleReadSerializer, TitleWriteSerializer,
                                UserEditSerializer, UserSerializer)
**from api_yamdb.settings import DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL**
from django.contrib.auth.tokens import default_token_generator
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from django.db.models import Avg
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from rest_framework import filters, permissions, status, viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action, api_view, permission_classes
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
from reviews.models import Category, Genre, Review, Title, User

from .mixins import CreateDestroyViewSet```


I use isort . and isort views.py but there are no changes.
````

Comment: I have highlighted a line with an error

Answer (score 0):

Just run

```
isort ./api_yamdb/api/v1/views.py --diff
```

and `isort` will tell you what it would expect.

This might depend on how you configured your sections ordering https://pycqa.github.io/isort/docs/configuration/custom_sections_and_ordering.html but my gut is the `api_yamdb` module is local so should be among the last import instructions.